# Bring active Bootstrap navbar link to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap navbar on my site with a collapsed menu that toggles on/off. I would like it so that when a user clicks one of the links in the menu (which is a dropdown, by the way), that active link should jump to the top of the menu. This way they can see a more expanded list of the dropdown items.

[image]

Here's a regular Bootstrap navbar. I want that when I click on "Dropdown", bring that active link to the top under "project name".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, from a user interface point of view I would strongly recommend against doing this. This is highly unexpected behaviour for the user who is likely to get confused as to why the thing they just tapped has moved. It could also cause mistakes from people opening the menu, then (since their finger is probably still close to the screen) accidentally clicking one of the menu items and being moved to a new page.

If you are worried about users not being able to see all the items maybe you should consider a different menu interface for your mobile devices such as an [off-canvas menu](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) (click the little 'toggle nav' button rather than the hamburner menu to see the off canvas menu). This would give you more space to play with for your menu items.

Comment: I have one dropdown that will have many options below it (a list of brand names) and that dropdown happens to be lower down on my menu list, so when user clicks it to expand, they'll only see maybe 4 brands. But if the brands dropdown jumped higher up when clicked, he'll get to see 10-15 brands.